# C# SQL Help! Insert Into is overwriting existing Data

Tags: c#, sql, insert-into

I'm learning SQL here in C# and am running into a bit of trouble.  I can't figure out how to insert data into my sql table WITHOUT overwriting the existing data.

I can easily add the values in the table, I even created a method to populate the data for testing and can easily and quickly add 500 values, but when I run it again, it overwrites the existing values as opposed to adding to it.

Here is my code:

```
public static void AddSongViaClass(Songs s)
    {
        string conStr = "TestSQL.Properties.Settings.ArtistConnectionString";
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(conStr)))
        {

            sqlcon.Open();

            try
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO Songs (Name, Id, Album, TrackNumber, TrackNumberCount, Genre, Rating, Tags, Subject, Categories, Comments, FileName, FolderName, FolderPath, FullPath, Length, PlayCount, SkipCount, LastPlayed)";
                query += " VALUES (@Name, @Id, @Album, @TrackNumber, @TrackNumberCount, @Genre, @Rating, @Tags, @Subject, @Categories, @Comments, @FileName, @FolderName, @FolderPath, @FullPath, @Length, @PlayCount, @SkipCount, @LastPlayed)";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", s.Name));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", s.Id));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Album", s.Album));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TrackNumber", s.TrackNumber));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TrackNumberCount", s.TrackNumberCount));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Genre",s.Genre));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Rating", s.Rating));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Tags", s.Tags));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Subject", s.Subject));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Categories", s.Categories));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Comments", s.Comments));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FileName", s.FileName));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FolderName", s.FolderName));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FolderPath", s.FolderPath));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FullPath", s.FullPath));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Length", s.Length));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PlayCount", s.PlayCount));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SkipCount", s.SkipCount));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LastPlayed", s.LastPlayed));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlcon.Close();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Count not insert. {0}", s.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Message {0}", ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
```

If someone could tell me what I need to do to simply add to the existing table without overwriting it, any help would greatly be appropriated.  Thank you!

If you're curious, this is my method for quickly populating my table:

```
 public static void JustDoIt()
    {
        Songs s = new Songs();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
        {

            s.Name = "My Song Name " + i.ToString("D3");
            s.Id = i.ToString();
            s.Album = "My Song's Album " + i.ToString("D3");
            s.TrackNumber = (i%13 == 0 ? 1: i%13).ToString("D3");
            s.TrackNumberCount = "12";
            s.Genre = "Something";
            s.Rating = (i%20/100*i).ToString("D3");
            s.Tags = "Tags " + i.ToString("D3") + " and more tags";
            s.Subject = "Subjects";
            s.Categories = "Categories";
            s.Comments = "Comments";
            s.FileName = "Ashes Remain - Christmas  - 02 - Gift of Love.mp3";
            s.FolderName = "My folder name";
            s.FolderPath = @"L:\Dropbox\Music\00- Sync'd Music\Ashes Remain";
            s.FullPath = s.FolderName + "\\" + s.FolderPath;
            s.Length = "3:" + i/60;
            s.PlayCount = "12";
            s.SkipCount = "1";
            s.LastPlayed = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            SQL_AddNewRecord.AddSongViaClass(s);
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: let the "ID" as primary key and use auto increment for that.

Comment: Is it throwing errors ? I dont know what is the structure of your SQL tqble, but I see that you are manually setting up the s.id which seems weird if it is an identity key

Comment: Can you show your connectionstring? And is this a desktop app or a web app?

Comment: Hello, I was just trying to populate it with data.  I'll change the id to auto populate.  No errors.  It compiles and runs fine.   I use SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2015 to confirm the data was written to my db.  It writes fine.  The connection string is simple: string conStr = "TestSQL.Properties.Settings.ArtistConnectionString"; And then strReturn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[conStr].ConnectionString;

Comment: I set the "ID" as the primary key.  It thought that the reason why it was overwriting my data was because the PK was repeating (between 1 and 500) so I did one iteration of 1-500 then ran it again only I changed my for loop to go from 501 to 1000.  No luck, 501-1000 overwrote 1-500.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to answer: This is a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", s.Name));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", s.Id));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Album", s.Album));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TrackNumber", s.TrackNumber));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TrackNumberCount", s.TrackNumberCount));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Genre", s.Genre));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Rating", s.Rating));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Tags", s.Tags));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Subject", s.Subject));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Categories", s.Categories));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Comments", s.Comments));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FileName", s.FileName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FolderName", s.FolderName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FolderPath", s.FolderPath));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FullPath", s.FullPath));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Length", s.Length));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PlayCount", s.PlayCount));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SkipCount", s.SkipCount));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LastPlayed", s.LastPlayed));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["Name"].Value = "My Song Name " + i.ToString("D3");
                    cmd.Parameters["Id"].Value = i.ToString();
                    ...All parameters...
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion and it filled with errors.  Not compile errors, just errors that got caught in my trap.  Here's one of 500 of them:  Error Message An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'Id' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.  To make matters worse.  I changed my iteration from 500 to 100, so it only inserted 100 into my DB.  when I opened it up, I expected to see 1 through 100 overwritten and 200 through 500 untouched, but what I found was there was only 1 through 100 in the DB.  The 200 through 500 disappeared.  It's almost like it dumps the whole table 1st.

Comment: AND now, I don't know what Im doing.  I realized I was looking at the db in my bin\debug folder, no the db in my solution's folder.  That's the one that was populating and it makes sense that it was *New* every time I ran the debugger.  NOW, I'm going to try to get it to update to the main DB in my solution's folder.

Comment: So, magic happened.  I took someone's advice and created my own DB and tables using MS Sql Mgmt studio.  I detached it, and put it in a location.  I added the connection to VS and deleted all other dbs that I was working on. when I added the connection and it asked me if I wanted to import that db in my project, I said NO!.  after I did that, ran program, **everything** updates perfectly.   Sorry for putting everyone on a wild goose chase, thank you for your help!